# Sorting events with dates in javascript object array and comparing with current date to display in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am writing a client side code, where we have a bunch of events students can register for. Each event has a date, on page load I want to compare the event date with current date and show only those events which are not over yet(not older than today), these events will be shown in a drop down. After reading other answers, this is what I have written. I am not able to find errors in this.

MY javascript:

```
  function addFormField() {
    var event=[]
event[0]={name:"calendarevent1", eventdate:"October 12, 2013"}
event[1]={name:"calendarevent2", eventdate:"November 2, 2013"}
event[2]={name:"calendarevent1", eventdate:"December 20, 2014"}

var today = new Date();

event.sort();

var nextLater = null;

for (var i = 0; i < event.length; i++) {
  if (event[i] > today) {
    nextLater = event[i];
    break;
for (i = 0; i < nextLater.length; i++) {
    $("#EventList").append('<option>' + nextLater[i] + '</option>')
}

  }
}
```

and the html for the drop down:

```
<select id= "Somename" name="Somename" id= "EventList" style="width: 267px;">
                  <option value="" selected>Select One:</option>

                </select>
```

I am fairly new at javascript, any pointers would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change a few things.
For starters you need to change the way you put the dates in the object, because you can not compare a date with that format. So change them to be `10/12/2013' (October 12, 2013).

Second, you compare `event[i]` with `today`, but `event[i]` is the object so you need to do `event[i].eventdate`.

```
function addFormField() {
    var event = []
    event[0] = {
        name: "calendarevent1",
        eventdate: "10/12/2013"
    }
    event[1] = {
        name: "calendarevent2",
        eventdate: "11/2/2013"
    }
    event[2] = {
        name: "calendarevent1",
        eventdate: "12/20/2014"
    }

    var today = new Date();

    event.sort();

    var nextLater = null;

    for (var i = 0; i < event.length; i++) {
        if (new Date(event[i].eventdate) > today) {
            //nextLater = event[i];
            //break;
            //for (i = 0; i < nextLater.length; i++) {
                $("#EventList").append('<option>' + event[i].name + '</option>')
            //}

        }
    }
}
addFormField();
```

Your fiddle has a few things wrong. You didn't add jQuery. Your `selectbox` has two id's remove the first one. I commented out a few things that stopped the code from populating the selectbox. And lastly, you need to call the function otherwise it won't do anything.

http://jsfiddle.net/7G9e5/1/

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I get it now. But it's not appending the array results to the dropdown. Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7G9e5/

Comment: Works like a charm, and explains where I was wrong. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Can you show one last thing, if the array also has values, how can that be appended in the above code?

Comment: What do you mean with array has values?

Comment: I used this from comment below. $("#EventList").append('<option value="' + event[i].value + '">' + event[i].name + '</option>')

Answer (score 1):

If thats the way you have your dates formatted that's fine, but you will have to do the following:

```
function addFormField() {

    var event= [];

    event[0]={name:"calendarevent1", eventdate:"October 12, 2013"};
    event[1]={name:"calendarevent2", eventdate:"November 2, 2013"};
    event[2]={name:"calendarevent1", eventdate:"December 20, 2014"};

    event.sort(function(a, b) {
          if (new Date(a.eventDate) > new Date(b.eventDate) return 1;
          if (new Date(a.eventDate < new Date(b.eventDate) return -1;
          return 0;
    });

    var today = new Date();

    for (var i = 0; i < event.length; i++) {
        if (new Date(event[i].eventdate) > today) {
            $("#EventList").append('<option>' + event[i].name + '</option>')               
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying this in jsfiddle and this does not populate the drop down. I don't see anything wrong with the code though. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I'm assuming that you want to add those values to the value attribute of the `<option>` In that case you would just do: `$("#EventList").append('<option value="' + event[i].value + '">' + event[i].name + '</option>')`